# Problem with php form

Tags: php, email, forms

I have been asked by a friend to amend some code for his contact form. I don't know php so this is proving quite difficult. I know fluent HTML and CSS though.

The form needs to send name and email details to his email AND redirect to a thank you page. The redirect works fine as does all of the errors etc but it won't send any mail! This is the code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['txtName'])){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_ezine WHERE email = '$_POST[txtEmail]'";
$result = dbQuery($sql);
$numRows = dbNumRows($result);
if($numRows > 0){
echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.thankyoupageishere.com';</script>";
}else{

if($_POST['txtEmail'] != "" && $_POST['txtEmail'] != "Email Address"){

$searchfor = "@";
$searchfor2 = ".";

$find1 = strpos($_POST['txtEmail'],$searchfor); // CHECK IF EMAIL CONTAINS @ SYMBOL
$find2 = strpos($_POST['txtEmail'],$searchfor2); // CHECK IF EMAIL CONTAINS . SYMBOL


if($find1 === false || $find2 === false) {
 // string needle NOT found in haystack
$errorStr = "Invalid email format.";
}
else {
 // string needle found in haystack
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_ezine (username, email, event) VALUES ('$_POST[txtName]', '$_POST[txtEmail]', 'hop')";
$result = dbQuery($sql);    
echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.thankyoupageishere.com';</script>";
}


}else{// FIELDS ARE BLANK OR UNCHANGED
    $errorStr = "Please enter your name and email to continue.";
}
}
}

?>

<div id="content" class="hop" style="min-height:220px;">

<div id="body" style="min-height:200px;padding-right:340px;">
    <h2>Sign up to download your photos</h2>
    <p>Complete the registration form</p>
<?php 
if($errorStr != ""){echo "<p style=\"color:#F00;\">" . $errorStr . "</p>";}
?>
<form name="hop" class="competition" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" value="Name" class="contact-name" name="txtName" /> <input type="text" value="Email Address" class="contact-email" name="txtEmail" /> <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT&gt;" class="submit" /></form>
</div>
```

Can someone tell me where I enter the email details!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

where is your mail function?

you should use  [php's mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to send emails.

[htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) will make the input secure, because you want to avoid  [xss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)  and  [sql injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)  .
Dont ever develop something as insecure as the code you posted.

```
$name=htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtName'],ENT_QUOTES); 
$email=htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtEame'],ENT_QUOTES);
mail("yourfriendsemail@gmail.com","(subject) A new mail","name: $name , email: $email");
```

Comment: Hi T4u many thanks, I didnt develop the code though. I'm just editing it. Where will I add that bit of script?

Comment: right before the [ echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.thankyoupageishere.com';</script>"; ] part.

Comment: this is my code now:  // string needle found in haystack
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_ezine (username, email, event) VALUES ('$_POST[txtName]', '$_POST[txtEmail]', 'bunnyhop')";
$result = dbQuery($sql); 
$name=htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtName'],ENT_QUOTES); 
$email=htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtEame'],ENT_QUOTES);
mail("info@email.co.uk","(subject) A new mail","name: $name , email: $email");
echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.thankyoupage.co.uk';</script>";
}

Comment: i accidently wrote "txtEame" instead "txtEmail". try to understand what i wrote, and also look at the php's mail function documentation. you will not be able to complete your task if you wont understand what you are doing.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be sending?

Answer (score 0):

It won't send any email because you haven't used the php mail() command anywhere.

You can find the full reference to the function and examples at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I'm really not proficient with php, could someone add in the extra code I need and publish it for me?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_ezine (username, email, event) VALUES ('$_POST[txtName]', '$_POST[txtEmail]', 'hop')";
$result = dbQuery($sql);    
/*send mail here*/
mail($_POST[txtEmail], 'Your email subject', 'your email content here', "From: youremail@yourdomain.com\r\n");
echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.thankyoupageishere.com';</script>";
```

But, before you go and make this code live,I would suggest you to use some readymade script. For example, `$_POST[txtEmail]` should be `$_POST['txtEmail']`. You are not filtering user input. Unsafe user input is a security hole. IMHO, if you do not have any interest in learning PHP or programming hire some freelance for 10$ to do the script rather than doing it yourself and landing in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You could try: (replace the 2 variables with the content you want).  I also fixed a few incorrect uses of the $_POST array (you forgot the single quotes around txtEmail in places)

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST['txtName'])){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_ezine WHERE email = '". $_POST['txtEmail'] . "'";
$result = dbQuery($sql);
$numRows = dbNumRows($result);
if($numRows > 0){
//************ EDIT THESE ****************
$subject = "Your email subject";
$message = "Your email message";
//****************************************
mail($_POST['txtEmail'], $subject, $message);


echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.thankyoupageishere.com';</script>";
}else{

if($_POST['txtEmail'] != "" && $_POST['txtEmail'] != "Email Address"){

$searchfor = "@";
$searchfor2 = ".";

$find1 = strpos($_POST['txtEmail'],$searchfor); // CHECK IF EMAIL CONTAINS @ SYMBOL
$find2 = strpos($_POST['txtEmail'],$searchfor2); // CHECK IF EMAIL CONTAINS . SYMBOL


if($find1 === false || $find2 === false) {
 // string needle NOT found in haystack
$errorStr = "Invalid email format.";
}
else {
 // string needle found in haystack
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_ezine (username, email, event) VALUES ('". $_POST['txtName']."', '".$_POST['txtEmail'].'", 'hop')";
$result = dbQuery($sql);    
echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.thankyoupageishere.com';</script>";
}


}else{// FIELDS ARE BLANK OR UNCHANGED
    $errorStr = "Please enter your name and email to continue.";
}
}
}

?>

<div id="content" class="hop" style="min-height:220px;">

<div id="body" style="min-height:200px;padding-right:340px;">
    <h2>Sign up to download your photos</h2>
    <p>Complete the registration form</p>
<?php 
if($errorStr != ""){echo "<p style=\"color:#F00;\">" . $errorStr . "</p>";}
?>
<form name="hop" class="competition" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" value="Name" class="contact-name" name="txtName" /> <input type="text" value="Email Address" class="contact-email" name="txtEmail" /> <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT&gt;" class="submit" /></form>
</div>
```

Comment: ah, I missed that, he needs to send email and insert the email in db. if the email is there then send somewhat different email otherwise send a welcome email and add email to db.